# Unnest a list column directly into several columns

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

Can I unnest a list column directly into *n* columns?

The list can be assumed to regular, with all elements being of equal length.

If instead of a list column I would have a character vector, I could `tidyr::separate`. I can `tidyr::unnest`, but we need another helper variable to be able to `tidyr::spread`. Am I missing an obvious method?

Example data:

```
library(tibble)

df1 <- data_frame(
  gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  values = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   gr    values   
>   <chr> <list>   
> 1 a     <int [2]>
> 2 b     <int [2]>
> 3 c     <int [2]>
> ```

Goal:

```
df2 <- data_frame(
  gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  V1 = c(1, 3, 5),
  V2 = c(2, 4, 6)
)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 3
>   gr       V1    V2
>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1 a        1.    2.
> 2 b        3.    4.
> 3 c        5.    6.
> ```

Current method:

```
unnest(df1) %>% 
  group_by(gr) %>% 
  mutate(r = paste0('V', row_number())) %>% 
  spread(r, values)
```

Comment: I don't know why but this works ? `library(splitstackshape);
cSplit(df1, "values", sep = ":")` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I think splitstackshape under the hood does what Victorp's answer is doing.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

with *tidyr 1.0.0* you can do :

```r
library(tidyr)
df1 <- tibble(
  gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  values = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
)

unnest_wider(df1, values)
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   gr     ...1  ...2
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 a         1     2
#> 2 b         3     4
#> 3 c         5     6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The output is verbose here because the elements that were unnested horizontally (the vector elements) were not named, and `unnest_wider` doesn't want to guess silently.

We can name them beforehand to avoid it :

```r
df1 %>%
  dplyr::mutate(values = purrr::map(values, setNames, c("V1","V2"))) %>%
  unnest_wider(values)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   gr       V1    V2
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 a         1     2
#> 2 b         3     4
#> 3 c         5     6
```

Or just use `suppressMessages()` or `purrr::quietly()`

Comment: The verbosity might change in future releases, if I forget to edit the answer when it happens please someone ping me here!

Comment: What if I have more than one column to unnest?

Comment: I had a similar problem. Each element of my list-column is a list of 3 numbers, and unnesting the column with unnest() would provide me only the first value. Why is unnest_wider needed?

Comment: Laura and @JASC check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690697/17055951) of Paweł Kozielski-Romaneczko.

Answer (score 13):

With `data.table` it's pretty simple:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df1)
df1[, c("V1", "V2") := transpose(values)]
df1
#    gr values V1 V2
# 1:  a    1,2  1  2
# 2:  b    3,4  3  4
# 3:  c    5,6  5  6
```

Comment: alternative for when the list-elements aren't of equal length: `df1[, rn := .I][, transpose(values), by = .(gr, rn)][]`

Answer (score 12):

```
library(tibble)

df1 <- data_frame(
  gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  values = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
)

library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(r = map(values, ~ data.frame(t(.)))) %>%
  unnest(r) %>%
  select(-values)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   gr       X1    X2
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 a         1     2
# 2 b         3     4
# 3 c         5     6
```

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this:

```
cbind(df1[, "gr"], do.call(rbind, df1$values))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data_frame(
  gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  values = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
)

df %>% mutate(V1 = sapply(values, "[[", 1), V2 = sapply(values, "[[", 2))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  gr    values       V1    V2
  <chr> <list>    <int> <int>
1 a     <int [2]>     1     2
2 b     <int [2]>     3     4
3 c     <int [2]>     5     6
```

Edit:

When the listed vectors are very long, and writing by hand `V1 = sapply(values, "[[", index)` is not convenient, then you can combine it with `f_interp` from `lazyeval`:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)
df <- data_frame(gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'), values = list(1:11, 3:13, 5:15))
nums <- c(1:11)
ll <- lapply(nums, function(nr) f_interp(~sapply(values, "[[", uq(nr))))
mutate_(df, .dots=setNames(ll, paste("V", nums, sep="")))

# A tibble: 3 x 12
  gr    values        V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <chr> <list>     <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 a     <int [11]>     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
2 b     <int [11]>     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
3 c     <int [11]>     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem several times. My solution is admittedly clunky compared to the other answers, but reporting it for completeness sake.

```
library(tibble)
df1 <- data_frame(
  gr = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
  values = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:6)
)

matrix(unlist(df1[1])) -> grs
matrix(unlist(df1[2]), byrow=T, ncol=2) -> vals
```

Result:

```
> data.frame(grs, vals)
  grs X1 X2
1   a  1  2
2   b  3  4
3   c  5  6
```

Comment: Thanks, but we definitely don't want to convert to `matrix` and coerce everything into characters!