# Split a list column into multiple columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a data frame where the last column is a column of lists. Below is how it looks:

```
Col1 | Col2 | ListCol
--------------------------
 na  |  na  | [obj1, obj2]
 na  |  na  | [obj1, obj2]
 na  |  na  | [obj1, obj2]
```

What I want is

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3  | Col4
--------------------------
 na  |  na  | obj1  | obj2
 na  |  na  | obj1  | obj2
 na  |  na  | obj1  | obj2
```

I know that all the lists have the same amount of elements.

Edit:

Every element in ListCol is a list with two elements.

Comment: It depends a lot on how `ListCol` is structured. If it contains a data frame or named list for each row, just `tidyr::unnest` will work. If it's some other structure, you may need to rearrange first. To get a better answer, edit with the result of calling `dput` on your sample data so we can reproduce the exact structure.

Comment: Hello. I've tried unnest but what it's been doing is getting the objects to separate, but in different rows rather than columns. Every row of ListCol is a list

Comment: The simplest way to get it to expand sideways instead of down is to make each list element a 1-row data frame, e.g. with `df$ListCol <- lapply(df$ListCol, function(x) as.data.frame(t(x)))` (with dplyr and purrr, if you prefer) and then calling `unnest`.

Comment: here's alisatire's solution for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889246/how-to-unnest-column-list using invoke_map and tibble. and here are several other solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689927/unnest-a-list-column-directly-into-several-columns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one approach, using `unnest` and `tidyr::spread`...

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#example df
df <- tibble(a=c(1, 2, 3), b=list(c(2, 3), c(4, 5), c(6, 7)))

df %>% unnest(b) %>% 
       group_by(a) %>% 
       mutate(col=seq_along(a)) %>% #add a column indicator
       spread(key=col, value=b)

      a   `1`   `2`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    1.    2.    3.
2    2.    4.    5.
3    3.    6.    7.
```

Comment: in your example you are just doing `cbind(df[1],do.call(rbind,df$b))` or even `cbind(df[1],t(data.frame(df$b)))`

Comment: @Onyambu, don't you want to write a complete answer to this post? It helped me and could help others but I missed it the first time.

Comment: Help doc for Spread says it's superseded by pivot_wider, which works nicely as well.

Answer (score 26):

Currently, the tidyverse answer would be:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% unnest_wider(ListCol)
```

Comment: You can also add the `names_sep` parameter if you need to keep the name of the nested column (e.g. `data %>% unnest_wider(ListCol, names_sep="_")` would lead to `ListCol_Col3`, which is handy when unnesting several columns at once).

Answer (score 5):

## Comparison of two great answers

There are two great one liner suggestions in this thread:

### (1) `cbind(df[1], t(data.frame(df$b)))`

This is from `@Onyambu` using `base` **R**. To get to this answer one needs to know that a `dataframe` is a list and needs a bit of creativity.

### (2) `df %>% unnest_wider(b)`

This is from `@iago` using `tidyverse`. You need extra packages and to know all the `nest` verbs, but one can think that it is more readable.

## Now let's compare performance

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(microbenchmark)

N <- 100
df <- tibble(a = 1:N, b = map2(1:N, 1:N, c))

tidy_foo <- function() suppressMessages(df %>% unnest_wider(b))
base_foo <- function() cbind(df[1],t(data.frame(df$b))) %>% as_tibble # To be fair
  
microbenchmark(tidy_foo(), base_foo())
```

---

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
 tidy_foo() 102.4388 108.27655 111.99571 109.39410 113.1377 194.2122   100
 base_foo()   4.5048   4.71365   5.41841   4.92275   5.2519  13.1042   100
```

#### Aouch!

`base` **R** solution is 20 times faster.

Comment: Using my real-world data & problem, I see less of a difference.  My data.frame has 100k rows, 65 cols, and I'm unnesting a single pair of variables.  The tidyr solution takes 12.5 seconds, the base R solution takes 11 seconds, so the base R solution is 1.14x faster.  Users might want to test on their own data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option with `data.table` and `base::unlist`.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(a = list(1, 2, 3),
                                 b = list(list(1, 2),
                                              list(2, 1),
                                              list(1, 1)))

for (i in 1:nrow(DT)) {
  set(
    DT,
    i = i,
    j = c('b1', 'b2'),
    value = unlist(DT[i][['b']], recursive = FALSE)
  )
}
DT
```

This requires a for loop on every row... Not ideal and *very* anti-`data.table`. 
I wonder if there's some way to avoid creating the list column in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

@Alec `data.table` offers `tstrsplit` function to split a column into multiple columns.

```
DT = data.table(x=c("A/B", "A", "B"), y=1:3)
DT[]

#     x y
#1: A/B 1
#2:   A 2
#3:   B 3
```

```
DT[, c("c1") := tstrsplit(x, "/", fixed=TRUE, keep=1L)][] # keep only first

#     x y c1
#1: A/B 1  A
#2:   A 2  A
#3:   B 3  B

DT[, c("c1", "c2") := tstrsplit(x, "/", fixed=TRUE)][]

#     x y c1   c2
#1: A/B 1  A    B
#2:   A 2  A <NA>
#3:   B 3  B <NA>
```